# What does "Stack Exchange" function as in "I love Internet forums, for example Stack Exchange"?

Tags: phrases, prepositions, parts-of-speech

Notice that in the sentence

***I love Internet forums, like Stack Exchange***

"like" is a preposition and "Stack Exchange" is its object.

Substitute "like" with "for example"

***I love Internet forums, for example Stack Exchange***

What does "Stack Exchange" function as in the latter sentence? An appositive? The object in an elliptical clause? Something else?

Or, to move the focus away from "for example" to the noun,

***I love Internet forums, particularly Stack Exchange***

"Particularly" is an adverb.  But what is "Stack Exchange"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't really function in a sentence; it doesn't have a specific role like the subject or the verb. It's just an idiomatic prepositional phrase used to link one utterance with a previous one as an example.

Comment: @JohnLawler I'll try something else to move the focus from "for example" to the noun.

***"I love Internet forums, particularly Stack Exchange."***

"Particularly" is an adverb. The question remains: what is the noun "Stack Exchange"?

Comment: "I love internet forums: Stack Exchange." is the same, I think. With "for example" an optional adverbial.

Comment: Yes, "Stack Exchange" is a proper name functioning as complement of "like". Your other example, "for example, Stack Exchange" is best analysed as a supplement, a loosely attached element set apart from the main clause by punctuation (and intonation in speech) presenting non-integrated content. The expression "for example" is classed as an 'indicator' serving to clarify the nature of its semantic relation to the anchor, i.e. the NP "Internet forums". In your last example, the adverb "particularly" is a partial focusing modifier in the the integrated NP "particularly Stack Exchange".

Comment: I'm going with an **object** in an elliptical clause: I like cats; I particularly like **tabbies**. --> I like cats, particularly **tabbies**.

Comment: @BillJ Thanks.  This seems to be it.  What is the difference between an "indicator" and a "partial focusing modifier"?  There must be many adverbs preceding nouns in NP supplements.  E.g. "Someone, ***probably*** an employee, stole the cash."  Thanks again.

Comment: The indicator is in some ways like a coordinator in that it links together the elements in the construction. On the other hand, partial restrictive focusing adverbs like "particularly"/ especially"/ "notably" etc. are heads of the expressions they modify. Your 3rd example doesn't mean that "I love only SE" but rather that I don't love anything else to the same extent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[In "**I love Internet forums, like Stack Exchange**",] "Stack Exchange" is a proper name functioning as complement of "like".

Your other example, "for example, Stack Exchange" is best analysed as a supplement, a loosely attached element set apart from the main clause by punctuation (and intonation in speech) presenting non-integrated content. The expression "for example" is classed as an 'indicator' serving to clarify the nature of its semantic relation to the anchor, i.e. the NP "Internet forums".

In your last example, the adverb "particularly" is a partial focusing modifier in the the integrated NP "particularly Stack Exchange"....

The indicator is in some ways like a coordinator in that it links together the elements in the construction. On the other hand, partial restrictive focusing adverbs like "particularly" / "especially" / "notably" are heads of the expressions they modify. Your 3rd example doesn't mean that "I love only SE" but rather that I don't love anything else to the same extent.    – BillJ 2022 Nov 22

Answer (score 1):

> "I love Internet forums, particularly Stack Exchange." "Particularly"
> is an adverb. The question remains: what is the noun "Stack Exchange"?

Rephrasing so that the adverb fits its role, I'd say the verb "love" is elliptical to avoid repetition.

"I love Internet forums; I **love** *for example/ in particular* Stack Exchange.

The focus-adverb phrase modifies the verb love, which has the noun as its object.

Comment: I can't upvote yet.  Just wanted to say thanks for the comment.

Comment: @femke_0 You should accept the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's not the right answer. In the OP's third example "especially" modifies "Stack Exchange", not "love", so that "particularly Stack Exchange" is a noun phrase.

Answer (score 0):

> I love Internet forums, for example Stack Exchange

Here you should consider the function of "for example "X".". It is a shortened form of *and here I give an example of an internet forum for you, "X"*

So in your example "Stack Exchange" is a proper noun that tells you what the example is.